# Обработка нескольких ошибок

Tags: javascript

Есть try...catch, в catch проверяются несколько условий if...else if... для обработки ошибок. Но не пойму как сделать так, чтобы все ошибки обработались, т.е. чтобы отработали все блоки, а не только первый:

```js
try {
    await action
}
catch (error) {
    const errors: ActionsExceptionInterface = {}

    if (error.code === "10") {
        errors.value1 = 'Произошла ошибки 10'

    } else if (error.code === "20") {

        errors.value2 = 'Произошла ошибка 20'

    } else if (error.code !== "10" && error.code !== "20") {
        errors.unknownError = 'Произошла ошибка, но я не знаю какая'

    }
    throw new CustomException(errors)
}
```

Проблема в том, что если в catch  должно упасть две ошибки, например 10 и 20 из примера выше, отрабатывает та, которая упала быстрее. Т.е. я хочу сделать так, чтобы в объект errors упали строки текстового описания ошибок, а затем выбросился ексепшн с итоговым объектом после всех проверок, но не до конца понимаю как это сделать, мб на промисах как-то или есть какой-то способ заставить нынешний код отработать. Подскажите как такое сделать, спасибо.

Comment: так убери везде else да и всё

Comment: Пробуйте использовать promise'ы, https://learn.javascript.ru/promise-error-handling

Comment: Не очень понятно, вы хотите из блока кода, который в try выбросить **две** ошибки? Так нельзя!

Comment: если коротко, то экшен принимает в себя набор данных, у них есть несколько полей, и они либо валидны и проходят, либо невалидны и все падает. Мб вопрос неправильно задал, если да то извиняюсь. Короче у меня все ожидаемо падает когда невалидно одно поле. Поле невалидно, все круто выдаем сообщение об ошибке что данное поле невалидно. Но вот если два поля невалидны, то выдается ошибка только на одно из них, вот и хотелось сделать как-то чтобы вылетели обе ошибки. Хотя вы правы, как оказалось эти две ошибки даже не появляются одновременно, проблему нужно искать в другом месте

Comment: `Конструкция try...catch пытается выполнить инструкции в блоке try, и, в случае возникновения ошибки, останавливает выполнение в блоке try, и выполняет блок catch.` Если вас такое поведение не устраивает, значит обработку ошибок вы должны делать другим способом.